# JqGrid local data custom validation failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have an implementation of jqgrid with a method that checks for duplicates cell entries.  This method is part of a custom validation method defined in editrules.  It appears to work ok, but once I delete rows from the grid, the **$grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');** seems to be getting messed up. I'm doing local deletes I scavenged as follows:

```
    delSettings = {
        onclickSubmit: function (options) {
            var gridId = $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id),
                gridP = $grid[0].p,
                newPage = gridP.page,
                rowids = gridP.multiselect ? gridP.selarrrow : [gridP.selrow],
                reloadLastPage = false;

            options.processing = true; // - reset the value of processing option which could be modified

            $.each(rowids, function () {  // - delete selected rows
                $grid.delRowData(this);
            });
```

This is the pertinent method, the idea is to check for rows with a duplicate entry, skipping the row being edited (selectedRowId).

```
function IsIDImagePathUnique(imagePath) {
    var status = true,
    $grid = $('#list'),
    selectedRowId = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
    gridData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    idsToDataIndexes = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');

$.each(idsToDataIndexes, function (id, index) {
    if (_editType === 'edit' && id === selectedRowId) // - skip edited row
        return true;

    if( gridData[index].IDImage === imagePath ) {
        status = false;
        return false;   // - break
    }
});
return status;
```

}

Help or comments appreciated.

**UPDATED:**
I still need to figure out what my issue was, but I came up with a workaround to avoid using the **$grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');** :

```
function IsIDImagePathUnique(imagePath) {
var status = true,
    $grid = $('#list'),
    gridData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    allowed = _editType ? 1 : 0,
    counter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    if (gridData[i].IDImage === imagePath && ++counter > allowed) {
        status = false;
        break;
    }
}
return status;
```

}

Comment: I think you should use the method getDataIDs() to get the existing IDs

Comment: Ok I will try that tomorrow thanks.